# scp : file transfer

Tags: scp

I missed typed by scp command - didn't give target remote directory.

scp file root@remote-machine

It didn't say any errors and I don't know whether file is transferred or not . what happened here?

Comment: `ls` is your friend..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was no transfer to the remote host. There should be a local copy called "root@remote-machine" in your current directory.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't include a `:` and then a filepath on the remote server.

The filepath can be blank (i.e. the default directory), but missing out the colon means it is treated as a local file path and not a remote one.

Answer (score 2):

It has not been copied to remote host, you've copied the file to file named "root@remote-machine". That's all.

Comment: Thanks,but seems like the file created in local machine called "root@remote-machine".